# MultiValueDictKeyError at /change-part/. In python django

Tags: python, django, if-statement, file-upload, path

So i try to make a upload image system, and i make two different type of image, there are static and dynamic

and i try to make a different act/function for thoose type, so i made a two if

one like this,

```
if len(request.FILES['img_dinamic']) != 0:
    part = WebPart.objects.get(part=partToChange)
    if len(part.dinamic_image) > 0:
        os.remove(part.dinamic_image.path)
    img_dinamic = request.FILES['img_dinamic']
else:
    img_dinamic = ""
```

and the other one is like this

```
if len(request.FILES['img_static']) != 0:
    img_static = request.FILES['img_static']
else:
    img_static = ""
```

and when i try to run the system, it appears some error like this

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /change-part/
'img_static'
```

any body can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*`request.FILES`* is a dictionary like object(Subclass of *dict*)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES). So when you try to access a key and if the key does not exist within the dictionary, *`dictionary[key]`* always raise *`KeyError`*. The solution is to use the `get` method instead.

```
img_static = request.FILES.get('img_static', "")
```

This will try to access the key `img_static` from `request.FILES`. If it does not exist default value(second argument) will be used.